# How to get code using vkontakte api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vk

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 where I need to access to vkontakte api. Does anybody know how to do this by code in C#? I need to send next url string:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize? 
client_id=APP_ID& 
 scope=PERMISSIONS& 
 redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI& 
 response_type=code& 
 v=API_VERSION
```

I dont know what I should to insert into redirect_uri and how can I get response_type?

Link with documentaion where I nothing to understand: http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial. Check it for implementing OAuth for Vkontakpe API

[Реализация oAuth-регистрации в проектах ASP.NET MVC 4 на примере ВКонтакте](http://codehint.ru/articles/2013-06-03_oauth_vkontakte_asp.net_mvc_4)

**UPD:**

More info.

[OAuth + ASP.NET (Часть 3): авторизация через vkontakte по протоколу OAuth 2.0](http://kosfiz.ru/2011/08/01/oauth-asp-net-authorize-with-vkontakte/)

[vk-oauth.cs](https://gist.github.com/hodzanassredin/2047623)

[VkClient.cs](https://github.com/carepass/code-samples/blob/master/CSync_ASP_MVC3/OAuth2/Client/Impl/VkClient.cs)

**UPD 2:**

Here you can find permission's list. You should put them in `scope` variable.
Example:

```
scope=friends,video,offline
```

[Vk API Permissions](http://vk.com/dev/permissions)

**UPD 3:**

> REDIRECT_URI – адрес, на который будет передан code. Этот адрес должен
>   находиться в пределах домена, указанного в настройках приложения.
>   Обратите внимание, в адресе должен содержаться используемый протокол.

So it means that, redirect is the uri of callback method, that should get response from Vk Api.

Comment: I'm already implement this but don't understand how to use this when I need to get for example mutual friends.

Comment: And last question: what about redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI? what I should use instead of redirect_uri in my localhost?

Comment: @BorHunter , check update. You should create a method in your controller for callback method.

Comment: @BorHunter , if I've answered your question, please, accept it. Thanks.